# Import a package from a specific bundle when it is available also in another

Tags: java, maven, osgi-bundle

There are two bundles (A and B) which exports package a.b.c and B is a third party bundle. A is used as a dependency by other modules which has imports for a.b.c. These modules should get the package from bundle A and not B. Without excluding a.b.c package from B using the `<Export-Package>` it is possible to provide a workaround to bundle A to restrict the modules to only refer the package from itself?

Comment: It sounds you are talking about OSGi there is one option to use `Require-Bundle` in your `MANIFEST.MF`...but that sounds like a design problem...having the same packages in two different bundles?

Answer (score 0):

In the module that uses A that already has a,b,c from other places, place an exclude inside the A dependency tag for that pom.

So, I'm confusing myself with the letters but if project BOB uses dependency A but you don't want BOB to pull a,b and c from A because it already has that from elsewhere then, in the pom.xml for BOB, within the A  tag you'd use and exclusion.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>sample.a</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-a from Project-A -->
      <artifactId>Project-a</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
```

Check out the full example at ['Exclude Dependencies'](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)